# Как объединить ячейки со смещением текста вниз?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сверстать такую строку таблицы?

Comment: задаёте ячейкам разный vertical-align - левой top, правой bottom

Comment: @humster_spb врядли надо выравнивать по низу. скорее сразу после первой ячейки. Можно в 2 строки с объединнеием ячеек и скрытием бордера сделать

Comment: @teran, почему вряд ли? судя по картинке - вполне. и проще гораздо, чем мудрить с объединением и скрытым бордером

Comment: @humster_spb так там не просто текст, а строки свяазаны между собой. число жил во втором столбец и цена в третьем.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо как-то так, настроив границы

```css
table  {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: .5rem;
}

tr td:not(:last-child){
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">текст текст текст</td>
      <td>1 линия:</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3 жилы</td>
      <td>120 руб</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5 жил</td>
      <td>150 руб</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Или так:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
td:not(.right) {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Измерение сопротивления изоляции...</p></td>
    <td><p>1 линия:</p><p>3 жилы</p><p>5 жил</p></td>
    <td class="right"><p><b>120 руб</b></p><p><b>150 руб</b></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```